# Spring Boot form verification annotation order issue

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Springboot, I need to perform form validation, and the following is my validation class:

```java
@Data
public class LoginForm {

    @NotEmpty(message = "用户名密码不能为空")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,20}$", message = "账号必须为5-20位字母数字")
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty(message = "用户密码不能为空")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9.,!@#$%^&*()_\\-+=]{5,20}$", message = "密码必须为5-20位字母数字字符且包含两种组合")
    private String password;
}
```

This is my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin/auth")
public class AuthController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Object login(@Validated @RequestBody LoginForm loginForm) throws AuthException {
        LoginResp result = authService.login(loginForm.getUsername(), loginForm.getPassword());
        return success(result);
    }
}
```

At this point, I used Postman to send a request to test the interface and found that both the username and password fields in the class contain two validation annotations. For usernames or passwords, the two verification annotations on these two fields will not be executed from top to bottom. This annotation order is completely random. Is this a bug. Because in my understanding, it should be verified from top to bottom. When the verification does not pass a certain annotation, future annotations should not continue to be verified.

Or, to put it another way, how can I modify it to achieve the functionality I understand.